# Monitor Color Inconsistency with Various Programs on "Calibrated" Screen

Tags: windows-10, firefox, colors, adobe-photoshop, windows-photo-viewer

First of all, I am using the free program Quick Gamma, but I figure it's better than nothing and it will have to do until I can afford something more professional.

I'm noticing that I'm not getting consistent coloring in Firefox, Photoshop CC, and (old) Windows Photo Viewer. Each one looks a tad different. I was using Windows Photo Viewer to display the test image initially while I made the corrections with the Intel HD Graphic Control Panel and Quick Gamma, but then I just perchance opened it in PS and noticed that my gamma corrections were once again off. I then opened the test image in Firefox and again off. So I did some searching to see if I could find out what program to use to display the test image while I tweak with the color settings and I discovered that it has happened to others, but they were using XRite(?) software.

I'm not really sure what to do. I'm not a professional (yet, knock on wood) but I would still like consistent color for when I do share my work and because I'm quite picky about it. I would really appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

I'm running Windows 10. Please let me know you need any more information to diagnose my issue.

Comment: Calibrating using software is always a big no. You must use something external to measure your gamma, brightness, etc. for true accuracy.

Comment: And you can expect differences between software that uses ICC profiles and software that doesn't. Additionally, how you've configured software that take colour profiles into account will also affect display colours

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is make sure you're saving your images with a color profile of sRGB IEC61966-2.1. This is industry standard for screen space color. This is what will display correctly in browsers and other computers by default, specially if those platforms don't honor color profiles.

Having set the color profile correctly, you may still see a slight color shift, but it shouldn't be that apparent. Keep in mind that different hardware (monitors) and apps can render color slightly different from each other. This true between Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.